# Intermembral index equation

Tags: r, math, equation

I am trying to code for intermembral index by using a large amount of data.

Below are the usable columns from a larger data set.
I tried this code to no avail and some other combinations including using function

```
  part1<-fra(ASLCOMPTEST$LHML + ASLCOMPTEST$LRML/ASLCOMPTEST$LFML + ASLCOMPTEST$LTML)%*%100
```

Also, is there a way to do it based on if a measurement is `NA` it'll use the right or left side of the same bone that is missing?

(IMI is `(humerus+radius/femur+tibia)*100`)

```
LHML    RHML    LRML    RRML    LFML    RFML    LTML    RTML
308.5   NA      229.0   NA      443.0   452.0   NA      365.5
311.0   310.0   NA      221.5   415.0   415.5   330.0   331.5
289.0   298.0   223.5   227.0   398.0   400.0   312.0   320.5
314.5   306.5   237.0   226.0   430.0   431.0   351.0   352.0
318.0   322.0   234.0   238.0   434.5   437.0   361.0   364.0
304.5   307.0   233.0   235.0   402.5   407.0   338.0   338.0
281.0   283.0   215.0   NA     385.0    403.5   315.0   317.5
278.0   285.0   NA      218.5   397.5   395.0   319.0   325.5
305.0   298.0   223.0   220.5   393.0   397.0   316.0   312.5
305.5   310.5   228.5   227.0   421.0   421.0   337.0   333.0
320.0   326.0   NA     244.0    431.0   431.0   357.0   357.0
```

Comment: You can use `*` instead of `%*%` (matrix multiplication operator). I don't know what `fra()` is meant to do.

Comment: thanks. `fra()` was for fraction but i don't think thats right

Answer (score 0):

figured it out…

```
    part1<-((ASLCOMPTEST$LHML + ASLCOMPTEST$LRML)/(ASLCOMPTEST$LFML + 
           ASLCOMPTEST$LTML)*100)
```

Comment: You might want to look into the `with` function, like `part1 <- with(ASLCOMPTEST,(LHML+LRML)/(LFML+LTML)*100)`